# Can i display email template as tab in salesforce app?

Tags: salesforce, email-templates

I want to design my Email template in my app itself.

So can I get an existing email template or any other third party tool is there? Am new to the salesforce.

I want to design my email template from my tab in my app

Comment: Why would you want to edit email templates in this fashion? Is there a reason you wouldn't just do it normally through the Setup menu? Sure seems like re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Yup.End Users are not intrested to do in classical way. I want to edit my email template in new tab...

Comment: You could do it with a Visualforce page and VF tab, although in my opinion it would be a pretty massive undertaking to replicate all of the standard functionality that Salesforce provides (especially if you are new to the platform as you mentioned). I am not aware of any AppExchange apps that provide this, and I wouldn't be surprised if there weren't any just because it's duplicating functionality that I've never really heard anyone have a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a visual force ui for the email template. This VF page can override your tabs or you can use them as inline pages in your tabs. An apex code can give the necessary functionality..